# MySQL Query - Magento specified attributes on one row

Tags: mysql, magento, entity-attribute-value

I'm a bit of a MySQL noob and have been trying to pull a list of products and multiple attributes from Magento.  I currently have the following query which pulls attributes 185 and 180.  However, these are being output in separate rows.  I want to edit the query so that the attributes are all on one row for each product.  My query is:

```
SELECT
    ce.sku AS sku,
    ce_decimal.value AS attribute1,
    ce_int.value AS attribute2
FROM catalog_product_entity AS ce
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
    ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal
    ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id
    AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id
    AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int
    ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id
    AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id
    AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
WHERE ce_decimal.attribute_id = '185'
OR ce_int.attribute_id = '180'
```

which gives the following result:

```
_______________________________________
sku      attribute1        attribute2
_______________________________________
543      NULL              105
543      34.95             NULL     
768      NULL              104
768      15.67             NULL  
_______________________________________
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
_______________________________________
sku      attribute1        attribute2
_______________________________________
543      34.95             105  
768      15.67             104 
_______________________________________
```

Do I need to use GROUP_CONCAT or something similar?  It's driving me crazy..  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could squash it with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sku,
       MAX(attribute1) AS attribute1,
       MAX(attribute2) AS attribute2
FROM (
  SELECT
    ce.sku AS sku,
    ce_decimal.value AS attribute1,
    ce_int.value AS attribute2
  FROM catalog_product_entity AS ce
  LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
    ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal
    ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id
    AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id
    AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int
    ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id
    AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id
    AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
  WHERE ce_decimal.attribute_id = '185'
     OR ce_int.attribute_id = '180'
) AS sub
GROUP BY sku;
```

If you have more than one value per sku, use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
 SELECT sku,
       GROUP_CONCAT(attribute1) AS attribute1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(attribute2) AS attribute2
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56f78/436/0)**</kbd>

Comment: @lpw So use `GROUP_CONCAT`